# ExportFactory<T,TMetaData - Get type of class which derives from T

Tags: c#, reflection, export

I'm using MEF, and this is the class member into which I compose the MEF dlls:

```
IEnumerable<ExportFactory<ITask,IMetaData>> myTasks
```

I need to discover what is the derived type of each myTasks element.
That means that if I loaded a MEF dll which contains a class called Task1 that implements ITask, I want to get the type of Task1.

```
IEnumerable<ExportFactory<ITask,IMetaData>> myTasks; //lets assume I composed all the MEF components in here
foreach (var task in myTasks)
{
    //here I want to get somethink LIKE:
    string innerDerivedType = task.innerType.Name //should return Task1
}
```

Problem is I can't figure out how to get the 'real' type.
Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: Would a simple check for the runtime type of a generic argument not work? `var type = myTask.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First().Name;`

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius this returns "ITask"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are storing all the factories in a `IEnumerable<ExportFactory<ITask,IMetaData>>`, there is no way you can determine the actual type of ITask without executing the factory's CreateExport() method (which I assume you don't want to do yet).

That being said: You are using the ExportFactory<,> with MetaData, so you could expand your IMetaData to contain a TaskType property. That would result in:

```
IEnumerable<ExportFactory<ITask,IMetaData>> myTasks = ...;
foreach (var task in myTasks)
{
    Type taskType = task.Metadata.TaskType;
}
```